# Do native Japanese speakers always omit い after て in present continuous tense across all conjugations in informal language?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, contractions

- 言っている > 言ってる
- 欲しがっています > 欲しがってます
- 見ていた > 見てた
- 行っていました > 行ってました

I'm trying to sound as native as possible, so I would like to know which the more common way is of speaking in the present continuous tense (while knowing that the grammatically correct way would be to include い after て).

Answer (score 5):

That happens very often, but it would be overgeneralizing to say that it ***always*** happens.

There are multiple levels of "informal speech" and it would be safe to say that the more informal the situation/conversation becomes, the more often the phenomenon in question occurs.

(It is not too informal to end sentences with 「ます」 or 「ました」 as in a couple of your example sentences, either.  Sorry, but as a native speaker, I can't help  noticing these little things here.)